# Exception treatment best practice

Tags: c#

I would like to know which is the best way to make a Exception treatment, because inside my `Try` statement, I have a lot of validations, and if I get some `Exception` there, my `Catch` statement can tell me what happens, but how could I know in which field occurs the `Exception` ?

**Sample Code**

```
try
{
   // If I get a Exception when converting to number, 
   // I will understand the error 
   // but how could I know where in my `Try` statement was the error ?
   int valor = Convert.ToInt32(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText.Trim());
   // A Lot of another validations here
}
Catch(Exception e)
{
      this.LogInformation(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: for all the `Convert`, if you are not 100% sure they are valid, you should use `TryParse` instead. E.g. for Int32: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practises would be not to use `Try-Catch` at all when you convert strings to numbers. Therefore you should use the `TryParse` methods like `int.TryParse`.

```
// note that here is also a possible error-source
string valorToken = xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText.Trim(); 
int valor;
if(!int.TryParse(valorToken, out valor))
{
    // log this
}
// else valor was parsed correctly
```

Apart from that, if you want to provide exact error messages you have to use multiple `try-catch` or handle different exception types (the most general `Exception` type must be the last).

Comment: But this was just an example, I have a lot of validations, not only `Convert.toInt32`. I just want get where my code stop in my Catch statement.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Convert.ToInt32 if you're unsure of the value. Use Int32.TryParse instead:

```
int valor;
if (Int32.TryParse(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText.Trim(), out valor))
{
     // Worked! valor contains value
}
else
{
    // Not a valid Int32
}
```

In addition you should not be using Exceptions to catch validation errors. Your validation code should calculate if the value is correct, rather than failing when it isn't. A validation class should expect to receive both valid and invalid data as input. Because you expect invalid input you should not be catching exceptions when it's invalid.

Come up with a test that checks if the data is valid and return true or false. Pretty much all numeric types have a TryParse method like the above. For your custom rules for other validation methods come up with a specification that defines exactly what valid and invalid input is and then write a method to implement that specification.

Answer (score 1):

Move *try..catch* inside loop. Thus you will know which item exactly caused exception

```
foreach(var xmlNode in nodes)
{
    try    
    {
       //
       int valor = Convert.ToInt32(xmlNode.ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText.Trim());
       // A Lot of another validations here
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       LogInformation(e.Message); // current item is xmlNode
       return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is even the remotest possibility that the value you're tring to parse will not be parsable, it is therefore not an exceptional circumstance, vis. should not be treated as an exception.

In this case, there is `TryParse`, which allows you to determine that the value is not valid for parsing:

```
int valor;
if(int.TryParse(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText.Trim(), out valor))
{
  // "valor" is sucessfully parsed
}
else
{
  // invalid parse - do something with that knowledge
}
```

Comment: But this was just an example, I have a lot of validations, not only `Convert.toInt32`. I just want get where my code stop in my Catch statement.

Comment: @Lucas_Santos - And my answer was just an example too. You should be doing something similar for everything you think could possibly fail.

Comment: you don't need to assign a value with `int valor = 0`, declaring with `int valor` is sufficient!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair - pedantic. An `int` is set to zero implicitly, I was just being explicit.

Comment: @Jamiec this is not correct ... there's a difference between declaration and assignment... declare the variable only to get a *slight* perf boost :)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair - pedantic raised to the power of pedantic now. You're saying dont assign the value to get a *performance boost*?! ooooooohkaaaaay.

Comment: @Jamiec you are not getting the point ... Anyway, please read: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/07/for-best-results-dont-initialize-variables.html. And, finally, I did not say "do not assign a value", I've said "you don't need to assign" which is something completely different. mind your tongue, and try to get my point :)

Comment: @Jamiec btw, assigning a value to the/an `out` variable always shows that the author of the code did not get the `out`-parameter, how it works and its usage ... sry for that pal, didn't mean to be rude!

Answer (score 0):

Unless its different Exceptions that get created (i.e. different classes) then you will need to handle this with different try catches.

Typically you can do:

```
try
{
   // If I get a Exception when converting to number, 
   // I will understand the error 
   // but how could I know where in my `Try` statement was the error ?
   int valor = Convert.ToInt32(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText.Trim());
   // A Lot of another validations here
}
Catch(IOException ioe) {
      // Handle, log
}
Catch(ArgumentNullException ane) {
      // Handle, log
}
Catch(Exception e)
{
      // Handle, log and potentially rethrow
}
```

You could also have individual try catches (which is kind of what most people would do I think) or nested try catches in your try block:

Like

```
// First block
try {
  // Convert here once
} catch (Exception ex) { 
 // Handle and log
}

// Second block
try {
  // Convert here once
} catch (Exception ex) { 
 // Handle and log
}
```

Not sure if that helps at all.

Comment: Your title mentioned Exceptions Best Practices. If its just number parsing then I would go for Tobsey's answer

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var stackTrace = new StackTrace(ex, true);

    var frame = stackTrace.GetFrame(0);

    var line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();

    var method = frame.GetMethod();
}
```